# Hadoop - Hive sub-queries - Not In Clause

Tags: hadoop, hive, subquery

I'm trying to run the following query on Hive:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM mydata
WHERE store NOT IN (SELECT store_out
                    FROM ( SELECT a.store as store_out, COUNT(*) AS CNT
                             FROM mydata a
                             GROUP BY store) TB1
                    WHERE CNT > AVG(CNT) + STDDEV(CNT) AND  CNT < AVG(CNT) - STDDEV(CNT))
```

But I'm getting the following errors:

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10249]: Line 3:6 Unsupported SubQuery Expression 'store': Correlating expression cannot contain unqualified column references.
```

How can I write this query in another way?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't have subqueries in a WHERE clause in Hive.

Comment: Hum...ok. I need to see how I can build the query in Hive. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have you exact data so it is hard to verify this but I would do something like

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT a.*
    , flg
  FROM mydata a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT store_out, flg
    FROM (
      SELECT store_out
        , cnt
        , 1 AS flg
        , AVG(cnt)         OVER () AS avg_cnt
        , STDDEV_SAMP(cnt) OVER () AS std_cnt
      FROM (
        SELECT store AS store_out
          , COUNT(*) AS cnt
        FROM mydata
        GROUP BY store ) x
      ) y
    WHERE cnt > avt_cnt + std_cnt AND cnt < avg_cnt - std_cnt ) z
  ON a.store = z.store_out ) final
WHERE flg IS NULL
```

Basically, left join the subquery and create a dummy column.  That column won't exists in the main table so where all the flg values are NULL, these are the stores you want. Hope this helps.

Comment: many thanks for your help!!! It gives me this error:
Not yet supported place for UDAF 'AVG' hive

Comment: edited.  can't have aggregate function in a WHERE clause either.